# Save custom control's properties into settings using property binding

Tags: .net, binding, settings, properties, save

I developed a custom control with two datepicker controls with some more function in it. This - and my other custom controls - are stored in a class library, I reference it in my windows forms application to use these controls on my forms.

I use .Net settings capabilities to store form control's state by using applicationsettings/propertybinding in visual studio ide. It works great, but not for my custom controls. How can I change my custom control's properties to be 'saveable'? I can not see custom properties in property binding windows.

E.g. I'd like to save my specialized datetime picker's control selected value selected dates. My control has methods, properties to get/set it, but in my windows forms application I can not see them as a bindable property.

Environment: c#, .net4, visual studio 2010

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decorate them with one of the SettingAttribute types.

There are two flavors out of the box, one for app settings and one for user specific settings.  It sounds like you need the ApplicationScopedSettingAttribute:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationscopedsettingattribute.aspx

Comment: Thanks, ver kind from you. By the way this feature of .net is poorly documented, I did not find any sample code over the internet...

Comment: A good starting point into the MSDN documentation for the Application Settings Architecture is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8eyb2ct1.aspx